# How can I watch tokens in Parity wallet?

Tags: tokens, parity

I love the Parity Ethereum wallet. It works very well. But I assumed it would automatically show any tokens I own if I watched contract that held the tokens.

For example if I watch singularDTV contract, it should show my singularDTV tokens, but it doesn't do that by default.

How do I get my parity wallet to show any tokens I own?

Comment: Which version are you using? Tokens are displayed by default on your accounts if you hold some.

Comment: I'm using Parity//v1.6.2-beta-8a27211-20170311/x86_64-macos/rustc1.15.1
and I am watching the new DevCon2 token contract in the UI.  When I enter the address of the account that holds the token into the balanceOf function on the contract, it returns '1' (as it should), but the token does not appear on the accounts page (nor on the account detail page when I click on that account). Oddly, the same token does show up under the same account when I start parity with --geth and look at the account in Mist.

Comment: Currently, parity only watches token registered with the _Token Registry_ (see applications tab).

Comment: Is the token registry per-user or is it system wide? I would've thought someone had already added it, if it was system wide.

Comment: It's network-wide, yes. I'm not sure, is the DevCon token ERC-20 compliant?

Comment: @5chdn When I try to register a new token it says `The address is not a regular token contract address`. I'm on parity --dev, does it make any difference?

Comment: Under Parity 1.7 I can see some tokens by going to Account and mousing over the question mark icon in the wallet that is linked to the tokens.

Answer (score 3):

To see balance of an account you should do like this:
1- Go to Contracts Tab (If it is not there enable it in Settings)
2- Click Contract you already watch or add it then choose it.
3- Under balanceOf click on address
4- click on address you want to see it's balance or enter it.
5- Click on Query
6- You can see it's balance without Decimal corrections there.

To transfer your tokens to another account you should do like this:
1- Go to Contracts Tab (If it is not there enable it in Settings)
2- Click Contract you already watch or add it then choose it.
3- Click on "execute"
4- in from account, Choose the account you want to transfer from.
5- in function to execute, choose transfer
6- in to address choose destination address.
7- in value choose the amount you want to transfer (Please pay enough attention to Decimals, Send very small amounts to be sure)
8- Click on "post transaction."

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I'm not asking how to watch a contract or transfer anything. I'm asking why, when I've already watched the contract, the token doesn't show up under the account I use to hold all of my tokens. I thought, if I watched the contract, the token should appear under the account on the accounts tab of parity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Close Parity (make sure it fully closed and not open in the background), and re-open.  If your synced you should now see the token in your account tab.