# ERC-20 token not showing up in wallet

Tags: erc-20

I bought LGD token on BittRex and it won't show up in my wallet. It's not a business I particularly support, but thought I could make some quick profit on it.

I bought EMV and EOS tokens on EitherDelta, and everything worked smoothly there.  From what I can tell BittRex sent the correct data to the LGD smart contract.

Transfer from Bittrex to my Wallet: 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd6522e36c8ea741149f86a173aefe9437e38b69ddc7a1d2f669a898d4b897640

My Wallet:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x006752624D45DbfeD473A273e96a0dAB97e5AD77

Comment: Why can't Etherscan identify this token?  When it seems to be defined: https://etherscan.io/tokens?q=lgd

Answer (score 1):

my similar problem was solved like this. But maybe you already did this

[Why don't I see my tokens in Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24541/why-dont-i-see-my-tokens-in-mist)

Comment: Ok Thanks! Apparently every wallet has a similar watch function, even EtherScan and Parity (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/how-can-i-watch-tokens-in-parity-wallet) for tokens that are not in the "Global Registry".

Comment: This was seems helpful too: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/how-can-i-watch-tokens-in-parity-wallet